# VideoView Black Flash

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a `VideoView` in a `FrameLayout` created dynamically, that load and play video from url.
The video is playing great but when i add the `FrameLayout` that contains the `VideoView` to `(activity,fragment,view,...)` a black flash appear.

After some search i have this solution:

```
<SurfaceView
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="0px"
android:visibility="gone" />
```

But i dont now where the `FrameLayout` will be added.